# How can i make python append to the next column?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to make python append all the data starting from count=1 to the next column but it prints it at the bottom of my result from count=0.
im using 'self' because of my class and function. the first time that 'count==0' it makes two columns. first column is my 'self.header' and the second one is 'self.oneVariableSum(self.times2)'. but once the count goes to 1, it adds 'self.oneVariableSum(self.times2)' to the bottom end of second column. but i need it to be in a new column instead.
i have the portion of that code below but i cant figure what i'm doing wrong.

```py
if (count==0):

        self.all.append([self.header,self.oneVariableSum(self.times2)])
else:
        self.all.append([[None,self.oneVariableSum(self.times2)]])
```

Comment: Could you add more information about how `all` looks like?

Comment: What is `self`?  Give a concrete example.  I suspect you have `pandas` dataframe, but if so, you should make that clear.  Don't make us assume things that are obvious to you!.

Comment: yes im using pandas but converted to pyhton arrays somewhere in the code. im using 'self' because of my class and function. the first time that 'count==0' it makes two columns. first column is my 'self.header' and the second one is 'self.oneVariableSum(self.times2)'. but once the count goes to 1, it adds 'self.oneVariableSum(self.times2)' to the bottom end of second column. but i need it to be in a new column instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.

Comment: With python lists it is awkward to talk about 'columns'.  The nth column is the nth item of each of the sublists.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other ones said, it's not really possible/easy to do it using python lists. i ended up converting it to a panda dataframe. and used the line below to append the new result in a new column.

self.result=pd.concat([all,all2],axis=1, sort=False)

This did the trick.